# Relation between Parameterized complexity and Approximation Algorithms

Tags: complexity-theory, approximation, parameterized-complexity

I want to know whether there is a relation between parameterized algorithms and approximation algorithms.

Like there will exist a fpt problem for problem P iff it have some f-approx algorithm.

I would be also happy if some one can give me reference.

Edit: It's just observation from my aspect that c-approx algo have fpt algo where c is constant. I am not able to prove it but I want contradicting example.

Also this implies there is a relation between kernel and the approximation algo.

Comment: What research have you done?

Comment: I think I have proof in one direction, I.e, fpt implies c-aprrox algo.  we will find the a k kernal for problem P then use this as approx algo solution. Now we can traverse k=1 to n for optimal parameter.

Comment: How does the size bound translate into a quality bound?

Comment: yeah, this works for linear kernel only did not notice earliar.